# Null data completion based on subsequent observation

Tags: r, tidyverse

I have a dataframe that looks like this:

```
C1<-c(3,0,16,4,5,0,0,27,5,3)
DF<-data.frame(ID=c(seq(1,10, by = 1)),C1=C1)
```

I want to replace the 0 values with the average value from the next non-zero row. There is usually a single row with the value 0 (the value in the next row divided by 2), but there are also two such rows (the value in the next row divided by 3).

This is the output:

```
C1<-c(3,8,8,4,5,9,9,9,5,3)
DF.sol<-data.frame(ID=c(seq(1,10, by = 1)), C1=C1)
```

Does anyone know an efficient way to solve this?

Thank you!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can simply create a grouping variable that checks for lagged zeros and then group by the grouping and calculate the mean. This means that you are not limited to 2 or 3. This should work for any n number of consecutive zeros.

```r
library(tidyverse)

C1<-c(3,0,16,4,5,0,0,27,5,3)
DF<-data.frame(ID=c(seq(1,10, by = 1)),C1=C1)

DF |>
  mutate(grp = cumsum((lag(C1, default = -999) != 0))) |>
  group_by(grp)|>
  mutate(C1 = mean(C1)) 
#> # A tibble: 10 x 3
#>       ID    C1   grp
#>    <dbl> <dbl> <int>
#>  1     1     3     1
#>  2     2     8     2
#>  3     3     8     2
#>  4     4     4     3
#>  5     5     5     4
#>  6     6     9     5
#>  7     7     9     5
#>  8     8     9     5
#>  9     9     5     6
#> 10    10     3     7
```

Answer (score 1):

Here is a `data.table` option

```
library(data.table)

setDT(DF)[
    ,
    C1 := {
        if (prod(C1) == 0) mean(C1) else C1
    },
    rleid(C1 * shift(C1, fill = 1) == 0)
]
```

and you will obtain

```
> DF
    ID C1
 1:  1  3
 2:  2  8
 3:  3  8
 4:  4  4
 5:  5  5
 6:  6  9
 7:  7  9
 8:  8  9
 9:  9  5
10: 10  3
```